# Android Google Maps basic map

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to display a very basic MapView on one of my activities, however, my MapView is forever blank never loading any map. Said MapView is just a 200px height of an activity that has other elements. I did not create a Map activity from the wizard.

My manifest has:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

<!--
     The API key for Google Maps-based APIs.
-->
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
    android:value="my real code" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

My build.gradle has the dependency:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.1'
```

My AndroidStudio HAS the GooglePlay package. Would you know what I am missing?

This is the xml code for my mapView:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/geolocationLinearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Geolocation"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This is my activity java class map declaration and loading:

Declarations:

```
MapView mapView;
GoogleMap map;
static final LatLng HAMBURG = new LatLng(53.558, 9.927);
```

Inside OnCreateView:

```
mapView = (MapView) view.findViewById(R.id.mapView);
mapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        map = googleMap;
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(HAMBURG, 15));
    }
});
```

Comment: Where is the mapView.onCreate(...) ?

Comment: I added mapView.onCreate(mBundle); and now I see the mapView with Google logo on the bottom left side, however the map is not loaded... Do I need to code anything else?

Comment: If the map is blank, the common issue is a bad API key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note : I'm assuming you have valid key**

```
mapView = (MapView) view.findViewById(R.id.mapView);     
mapView .onCreate(null);
mapView.getMapAsync(...)
```

And also use other required methods like below, see the documentation below for all methods

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mapView .onResume();
}
```

- Check [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapView)
- Check [google sample](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples/blob/master/ApiDemos/app/src/main/java/com/example/mapdemo/RawMapViewDemoActivity.java)